# Do diffeomorphisms act transitively on a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $x,y\in M$. Must there exist a diffeomorphism $f : M \rightarrow M$ with $f(x) = y$?

I tried proving this via vector fields, i.e. trying to find a vector field whose flow through $x$ passes through $y$, without much success. Besides, this only has a chance of working on complete manifolds. Anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: Do you assume that $M$ is connected?

Comment: Yes, lets assume $M$ is connected. Otherwise this is rather trivially false.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No; take $M$ to be the disjoint union of two smooth manifolds which are not diffeomorphic.

However, the statement is true if $M$ is connected. You do not need completeness. It suffices to show that the set of all points that can be reached from $x$ via some diffeomorphism is both open and closed.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking an open disk disjoint union  and an open interval.

Comment: Maybe a better way to phrase the hint is as follows: define $x \sim y$ if $x$ can be reached from $y$ via some diffeomorphism. Show that this is an equivalence relation and that the equivalence classes are open.

Answer (score 17):

You can find a demonstration of this fact (if M is connected) in the book of Milnor - Topology from the differentiable viewpoint. It is the lemma of homogeneity. In fact you have more :

**Homogeneity Lemma: Let $y$ and $z$ be arbitray interior points of the smooth, connected manifold M. Then there exists a diffeomorphism $f:M\rightarrow M$ that is smoothly isotopic to the identity and carries $y$ into $z$.**

Comment: Way cool, Kaye.  +1 for you!

Comment: @ncmathsadist or Tomas could you please make me understand the lemma? I am not able to grasp after some stage for example from the step where he introduced some differential equation.