# Two points can be connected by a diffeomorphsim.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

$M$ is a connected manifold, for any two points $x,y$, we can find a smooth diffeomorphism $f:M\rightarrow M$ such that $f(x)=y$.

How to use connectness?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do diffeomorphisms act transitively on a manifold?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205697/do-diffeomorphisms-act-transitively-on-a-manifold)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the flow of vectors fields. Let $x$ be an element of $M$ and $U$ a chart which contains $x$, you can suppose $U$ is an open subset of $R^n$ there exists $V\subset U$ which is open such that every element of $V$ can be connected to $x$ by the flow of a linear vector field that you can extend to $M$ with a cut off function.

Since $M$ is connected, you have a path $c:[0,1]\rightarrow M$ between $c(0)=x$ and $c(1)=y$.You can write $[0,1]=\bigcup I_n$ where $I_n$ is an interval such that $c(I_n)$ is contained in a chart where every point are connected by a flow and $I_n\cap I_{n+1}$ is not empty, you can write $x_0 =x, x_1\in I_0\cap I_2, ...x_{l-1}\in I_{l-1}\cap I_l, x_l =y$ and $x_{i+1} =f_i(x_i)$ where $f_i$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: So you choose a vector field and this gives you for every chart an open set where $x$ is connected to every point of the set through the flow of that vector field?

What do you mean by extend to $M$ with a cut of functions?