# Let $M$ be a connected manifold, $p,q\in M$ two points, then does there exist some $F:M\to M$ a homeomorphism s.t. $f(p)=q$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

Of course, we have that $p$ and $q$ can be connected by a path, since $M$ is locally Euclidean and therefore locally path-connected. My suspicion is that this statement, and the proof goes something as follows:

Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ be a path from $p$ to $q$, and cover $\gamma([0,1])$ by open sets $U_1,\ldots,U_k$ where $f_i:U_i\to B(0,1)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\big|\ |x|<1\}$ is a homeomorphism for all $i$, and such that there exist points $p_i\in U_i\cap U_{i+1}$ for all $1\leq i\leq k-1$, with $p_0=p,\ p_k=q$. Let $F_0:M\to M$ be the identity map, then we need only modify $F_0|_{U_1}:U_1\to U_1$ and extend to $M$ to get some homeomorphism $F_1:M\to M$ where $F_1(p_0)=p_1$. Once this is done, we proceed by basic induction, and let $F$ be the composition of the $F_i$.

However, I'm stuck on how to defined $F_1$ from $F_0$. I have some intuition about how to deform $U_1$, but I can't see how to formalize it, or how to ensure that ensure that $F_1$ is continuous.

I'm also curious if an idea like this holds for smooth manifolds as well.

Comment: The smooth case is done in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/205697/258909). The same argument yields the result for topological manifolds, with "diffeomorphism" replaced by "homeomorphism".